# Printing triangle with word characters in JavaScript using recursion only

Tags: javascript, string, recursion

Interview Question: I was asked to write a recursive JavaScript function that takes an P character long String as input, and prints out the following:

1. The first line prints the first character of the string
2. The second line prints the first two characters of the string
3. and so on until Pth line prints all the characters of the string
4. (P+1)th line prints first (P-1) characters
5. (P+2)th line prints first (P-2) characters
6. and so on until (2P -1) th line prints only the first character

And if we run the function  : printTriangle("A Joke")

It will printout the following:

A

A

A J

A Jo

A Jok

A Joke

A Jok

A Jo

A J

A

A

I was asked to write this function in the interview, I could only write using iterative approach. Still wondering how to write that using recursive approach, can anyone enlighten?

Comment: You can add optional second argument to the printTriangle() function. If this is for the interview, I believe it would be fair to try do it yourself.

Comment: One way to do it would be to let your function print a substring both before *and after* calling itself. Each call tells the next call to draw a longer substring, until the full string is printed.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet I've gone and made an answer using that approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```js
function triangle(str, i) {

  if(i === 0) return;
    
  i = i || 1;
    
  if(i > str.length) return triangle(str, -1*str.length+1) ;
    
  console.log(str.substr(0, Math.abs(i)));
    
  return triangle(str, i+1) ;
}

triangle("A Joke");
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution, as Pieter Witvoet alludes to, that uses a single recursive call and two prints. It's simpler, and hopefully more understandable, than the others, because it uses a recursive *approach* instead of iteration dolled up as tail recursion.

```js
function triangle(str, i) {
  i = i || 1;
  var start = str.substr(0, i);

  console.log(start);
  if (i < str.length) {
    triangle(str, i + 1);
    console.log(start);
  }
}

triangle("A Joke");
```

Answer (score 0):

This my solution using Recursion in Functional JavaScript.

```js
(function(window) {
  var recursion = function(str, index, canReverse) {
  var index = !index ? 0 : index,
      result = str.substring(0, index),
      len = str.length;
    console.log(result);
    if (index < len && !canReverse) {
      recursion(str, ++index);
    } else if (index > 0) { // reverse
      recursion(str, --index, true);
    }
  };
  recursion('A joke')
})(window);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Prints "A Joke" twice. Also the interviewer said me that in recursive approach don't use any loops.

Comment: Also correct me if I am wrong, this is not recursive approach.

Comment: I have added an example with recursion.

Answer (score 0):

```
        function rPrint(val, num) {
        var n2 = num;
        if (num > val.length)
            n2 = val.length- Math.abs(val.length - num);
        document.write("<br>" + val.toString().substr(0, n2));
        if (num < val.length*2)
            rPrint(val, ++num);
    }
```

Then use it like `rPrint("A Joke",1);`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another recursive solution.

```js
var i = 1; //counter

/*Recursive function*/
function printTriangle(str) {
  var len = str.length;
  if (len > i) { //process string in default order
    console.log(str.substring(0, i));
    i += 1;
    return printTriangle(str);
  } else if (len > 0) { //process string in reverse order
    console.log(str);
    var sub_str = str.substring(0, str.length - 1);
    return printTriangle(sub_str);
  } else {
    return str;
  }
}

/*Process string*/
printTriangle("A Joke");
```